# Time difference between php timestamps in hours

Tags: php, timestamp

I have a php timestamp `1331875634` generated using php `time()` function.

I have the current timestamp generated using same function.

```
<?php
$time1 = "1331875634";
$time2 = time();

echo $differencem; //time difference in minutes
echo $differenceh; //time difference in hours
?>
```

I want to know the difference between these two in minutes. The minutes may be divided by 60 to make it in hours.

Comment: I think you are not go through the php manual for time difference in php.net.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You get the different in seconds if you subtract them, so divide it by 60 to get minutes and by 60 again to get hours.

Answer (score 14):

I created this code to take standard PHP UNIX TIMESTAMP, calculate the difference in time and return a standard time or a specialized time format.  This is great for timing a project and calculating the time it takes to get the results.

```
function timerFormat($start_time, $end_time, $std_format = false)
{       
$total_time = $end_time - $start_time;
$days       = floor($total_time /86400);        
$hours      = floor($total_time /3600);     
$minutes    = intval(($total_time/60) % 60);        
$seconds    = intval($total_time % 60);     
$results = "";
if($std_format == false)
{
  if($days > 0) $results .= $days . (($days > 1)?" days ":" day ");     
  if($hours > 0) $results .= $hours . (($hours > 1)?" hours ":" hour ");        
  if($minutes > 0) $results .= $minutes . (($minutes > 1)?" minutes ":" minute ");
  if($seconds > 0) $results .= $seconds . (($seconds > 1)?" seconds ":" second ");
}
else
{
  if($days > 0) $results = $days . (($days > 1)?" days ":" day ");
  $results = sprintf("%s%02d:%02d:%02d",$results,$hours,$minutes,$seconds);
}
return $results;
}

Example:

$begin_routine_time = time();
echo(timerFormat($begin_routine_time, $time()));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1331875634));
$datetime2 = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$oDiff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $oDiff->y.' Years <br/>';
echo $oDiff->m.' Months <br/>';
echo $oDiff->d.' Days <br/>';
echo $oDiff->h.' Hours <br/>';
echo $oDiff->i.' Minutes <br/>';
echo $oDiff->s.' Seconds <br/>';
```

Comment: you need to add this to get the exact total hour difference `$totalHourDiff = ($oDiff->y * 365.25 + $oDiff->m * 30 + $oDiff->d) * 24 + $oDiff->h + $oDiff->i/60;`

Answer (score 4):

Once I needed to convert seconds to time like 1 day 03:34:13 days hours:minuts:secondes

I wrote this function

```
function sECONDS_TO_HMS($seconds)
  {

     $days = floor($seconds/86400);
     $hrs = floor($seconds/3600);
     $mins = intval(($seconds / 60) % 60); 
     $sec = intval($seconds % 60);

        if($days>0){
          //echo $days;exit;
          $hrs = str_pad($hrs,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
          $hours=$hrs-($days*24);
          $return_days = $days." Days ";
          $hrs = str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
     }else{
      $return_days="";
      $hrs = str_pad($hrs,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
     }

     $mins = str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
     $sec = str_pad($sec,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

     return $return_days.$hrs.":".$mins.":".$sec;
  }

echo sECONDS_TO_HMS(65); // 00:01:05
echo sECONDS_TO_HMS(76325); //21:12:05
echo sECONDS_TO_HMS(345872); // 4 Days 00:04:32
```

I think it could be helpful for you.

Comment: `return sprintf('%s%02d:%02d:%02d', $return_days, $hrs, $mins, $sec);` and you don't need any str_pad.