# Difference between timestamps in minutes in PHP

Tags: php, date

I want to get difference between 2 timestamps of format `Y-m-d H:i:s` in minutes in PHP.
The code used is,

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$userLastActivity = date($date);
$timeLapse = (($currentDate - $userLastActivity)/60);
```

Here, `$date` is obtained from database. 
The value of `$timeLapse` is 0 in output. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Time difference between php timestamps in hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732553/time-difference-between-php-timestamps-in-hours)

Comment: well you don't have time stamps you have dates.

Comment: or you can try this link one the shortest answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67445652/14913109

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using unix timestamp. Practically it measures the time in seconds from 1/1/1970 and it's a lot easier to use and understand than a php object.

```
$currentTimestamp = new DateTime()->getTimestamp();
$userLastActivity = date($date)->getTimestamp();
$timeLapse = (($currentDate - $userLastActivity)/60);
```

You should have the time saved as timestamp on the server too, in that case you could use the $date directly as a number, with no need for a conversion. And also, because it's universal, you can pass it around to javascript or any other language without any worries for conversion

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` to parse textual datetime into a Unix timestamp and substract `$userLastActivity` from `$currentDate` and divide by `60`.

See if this helps -

```
<?php
$currentDate = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date = "2016-10-11 02:40:50";
$userLastActivity = strtotime($date);
echo round(abs($currentDate - $userLastActivity) / 60). " minutes";
?>
```

For more details :[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score -1):

Change these 2 lines for a start, as I don't think dividing dates by 60 is gonna work to well.

```
$currentDate = time();
$userLastActivity = strtotime($date);
```

That way you have time stamps and not dates (string)

Comment: Your second example is very wrong. That $interval->i is only returning the remaining minutes out of 60. You have to calculate the days, hours, minutes and seconds into minutes if you want to use diff function.

Comment: @MichaelHanon - I don't feel like fixing it, it was [optional] stuff anyway.  That's what I get for coding just in my head.  Besides I think the question was changed sense I posted this.. ie `date($date)->getTimestamp()` syntax error  call to method on non-object